# Animating xsl DropshadowEffect over click event

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, xslt, dropshadow

Hy everybody. 
I have a ".xaml" style sheet applied on several button elements on my code, and need to change the DropshadowEffect characteristics when the button is clicked. 
My code is like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type MyBtn}">
...
<Setter Property="Effect">
   <Setter.value>
      <DropshadowEffect BlurRadius="10" ShadowDepht="5" Direction="-45"/>
   </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
...
<Setter Property="Template">
   <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Mybtn}">
      ...
      <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
         <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
            <!-- Here I can change background and font colors properly, 
                 but can't change the shadow of my buttons -->
         </Trigger>
      </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
   </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>
```

Is there a way to change the DropshadowEffect through click or pressed events?
Thanks!

Comment: +1 to negate the unexplained down-vote you got since those help nobody. However, if you do a quick search for something like "animating drop shadow effect xaml" in your favorite search engine, you'd have an answer pretty quick. You'd just be applying an animation against the properties of your Dropshadoweffect after you give it an x:Name. Also, you have ShadowDepth misspelled in your example. Either way, give it a shot and come back once you've tried something. Welcome to SO. :)

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try. Thanks very much!